# Metrics/ParameterLists: Method has too many optional parameters. [4/3] Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, rubocop

All params are required

```
  class Library
    attr_accessor :authors, :books, :orders, :readers
      def initialize(authors = [], books = [], orders = [], readers = [])
        @books = books
        @orders = orders
        @readers = readers
        @authors = authors
      end
  end
```

Tried to make hash but it didn't work

```
class Library
  attr_accessor :authors, :books, :orders, :readers
    def initialize(**params)
      @authors = params.fetch(:authors, [])
      @books = params.fetch(:books, [])
      @orders = params.fetch(:orders, [])
      @readers = params.fetch(:readers, [])
    end
end
```

Metrics/ParameterLists: Method has too many optional parameters. [4/3]
def initialize(authors = [], books = [], orders = [], readers = [])

That's what i get and i need to make params as an empty arrays

Comment: Does a library really have authors? I would argue it does not it has books and these books have an or several authors. Some for the readers. A library doesn't have readers, books have readers, or books have loans and these loans are connecting readers with books. That said, IMO your model has too many associations and that leads to too many parameters.

Comment: Yeah it does, that's the point of the task i think, to figure out how to work with associations. Keyword params worked

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to used keyword parameters:

```rb
def initialize(authors: [], books: [], orders: [], readers: [])
  @authors = authors
  # ...
end
```